# Automatic sound effect on bounce

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor, video, audio

Using physics simulation, I have created a ball bounce that looks something like this:

[image]

**How can I automatically add a sound effect on each bounce?**

- The sound is from a provided sound file ([example: `Retro Jump 04.wav`](https://freesound.org/people/MATRIXXX_/sounds/503461/)) and is not generated inside Blender.
- It should be louder on the first bounce when velocity is higher on impact, and quieter as the velocity decreases.
- It should also be quieter the farther away it is from the camera.
- It needs to be automatic since I will have more than just one ball.
- It does not need to be perfect. For example, if there are walls blocking the way, the walls can be ignored. Echo is not required.

Scripting to add sound strips on impact is acceptable.

Comment: nice description. But i don't see any effort you made to this. What did u try? Where did u fail? Do you know python? or r u just searching for someone who does the work for u for free?

Comment: @Chris I have added https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/301883/168154 on where I am stuck.